# Can you nest C preprocessor directives?

Tags: metaprogramming, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

For instance, is the following possible:

```
#define definer(x) #define #x?
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need it?

Comment: one use is letting CPP evaluate a statement twice in different contexts. I have a system that uses grep/sed to expand vector equations by doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your syntax is invalid, the answer to your question is technically yes.  But it can only be accomplished by nasty tricks that make your code unreadable and unmaintainable.

See also: http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1995_vanschnitz and http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2004_vik2

Comment: I can't see the Yes within the links.. only weird obfuscated C code, could you put an example of that?

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't do that.
The pound (`#`) symbol has a different meaning while in a definition. it means - if this is an argument, make it a string by quoting it.

Comment: The technical term for that is the stringizing operator (and ## is the token-pasting operator).

Comment: Err.. have you seen assert() lately? In its simplest form:

#define assert(expr) if (!(expr)) { printf("Assertion failed (%s) at file '%s', line %d.\n", #expr, __FILE__, __LINE__); abort();}

So, really, you can, however its an abuse of the preprocessor. If your mindful of how you call it ... its ok

Comment: Also, commenting on the braindeadedness of assert, if you can't allocate 10 bytes, assert() is also bound to fail. Bad real world example but illustrates my point.

Comment: I fail to see how assert is even remotly related to this answer or question

Comment: That assert macro is, in fact, using the # stringification operator.  #expr creates a C-string of the argument to assert(expr).

Answer (score 8):

You cannot nest C preprocessor directives. Luckily, it is almost never necessary.
If you really need that kind of power, you will almost certainly be better off with another
preprocessor that you run before handing off the code to the C compiler. For example:

```
sed 's/@CUSTOMER@/J. Random Person/' foo.c.in > foo.c
cc foo.c
```

Another useful trick is to isolate the trickery into a single header file, which is
generated by a program you write yourself:

```
./generate-trickery --greet 'J. Random Person' > foo.h
```

where foo.h will look like something like this:

```
#define GREET(x) ("J. Random Person greets you, " #x)
```

If you tie this together with a Makefile, or some other automation, it will be
pretty seamless and not trip up your development much.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that.

You can reference one macro from another, but you cannot define one macro from another.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create a segment of preprocessor code that can be called multiple times to perform slightly different things, one (moderately awful) way you can do this is to isolate the code into a single `.h` file which you then `#include` several times.  The idea is that each time you `#include` the file you are "calling your routine" -- you "pass arguments" by first `#define`ing certain preprocessor constants that the included file refers to.

One place where I've seen this be useful is in generating "smart" enumerations that can convert to/from their "stringized" forms (which is useful for I/O).  You create a `.h` file containing e.g.

```
ENUMVAL(foo)
ENUMVAL(bar)
ENUMVAL(baz)
```

and then later `#include` this file twice: once where `ENUMVAL()` is defined in such a way as to create an `enum` declaration, and once when `ENUMVAL()` is defined in such a way as to produce an array of stringized names.  By doing it this way, you don't need to specify the list of actual tokens more than once.

Comment: This technique is called X-Macro

Comment: @qrdl and j_random_hacker: +1 for X-Macro. Checked [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289) on Dr.Dobbs and found it useful for some situations involving different parts of the code with lists of parameters with similar names. There's also [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) which explains a little more but shows less code.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define definer(x) #define #x?
```

#x is a stringification of x.  You can't #define a string token.  (#define "foo".)  It has to be an identifier **[a-zA-Z0-9_]*** token.

You **can't** nest #define's like that.  You can't have a #define in a #define.

You **can** have #if's inside #if blocks.

```
#ifdef FOO

#ifdef BAR
 ...
#else // BAR
 ...
#endif // BAR

#else // FOO
 ...
#endif //FOO
```

You are also somewhat limited as to the expressions you can use in #if macros.  But you can sometimes work around that.  For example:

```
        /* Use CONCATENATE_4_AGAIN to expand the arguments to CONCATENATE_4 */
#define CONCATENATE_4(      a,b,c,d)  CONCATENATE_4_AGAIN(a,b,c,d)
#define CONCATENATE_4_AGAIN(a,b,c,d)  a ## b ## c ## d

    /* Creates a typedef that's legal/illegal depending on EXPRESSION.       *
     * Note that IDENTIFIER_TEXT is limited to "[a-zA-Z0-9_]*".              *
     * (This may be replaced by static_assert() in future revisions of C++.) */
#define STATIC_ASSERT( EXPRESSION, IDENTIFIER_TEXT)                     \
  typedef char CONCATENATE_4( static_assert____,      IDENTIFIER_TEXT,  \
                              ____failed_at_line____, __LINE__ )        \
            [ (EXPRESSION) ? 1 : -1 ]
```

Plus something like:

```
STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(int1) == 1, sizeof_int1_equal_1 );
```

(Yes, I know about *#include <stdint.h>*.  It's just an example.)