# C++ Combining #define and #ifndef macro

Tags: c++, macros

I was wondering if there's a way to combine #define and #ifndef macro..

What this means is that I want to use #ifndef macro within the #define macro..

Since it's kind of hard to explain,, this is an example of what I want to do:

```
#define RUN_IF_DEBUG                \
    #ifndef DEBUG_MODE              \
        ;      // do nothing        \
    #else                           \
        cout << "Run!" << endl;     \
    #endif

int main() {
    RUN_IF_DEBUG
}
```

So I want the **RUN_IF_DEBUG** macro to run ONLY IF the **DEBUG_MODE** is defined...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can do nested defines without the "\" at the end of the line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you nest C preprocessor directives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427220/can-you-nest-c-preprocessor-directives)

Comment: @cerkiewny, You can't do nested defines period (at least without hacks) since you can't use other directives save `_Pragma` in macros.

Answer (score 5):

It is usually done the other way around:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_MODE
#  define RUN_IF_DEBUG ;
#else
#  define RUN_IF_DEBUG cout << "Run!" << endl;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do

```
#ifndef DEBUG_MODE
    #define RUN_IF_DEBUG ;      // do nothing
#else
    #define RUN_IF_DEBUG cout << "Run!" << endl;
#endif
```

You can't put other preprocessor statements within a macro's body.

As from the [c++ standards definitions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)<sub>draft</sub> section

> #### 16 Preprocessing directives
>
> ...
>   control-line:
>   ...
>   `# define` *identifier* replacement-list new-line
>   `# define` *identifier* lparen identifier-listopt) replacement-list new-line
>   `# define` *identifier* lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
>   `# define` *identifier* lparen identifier-list, ... ) replacement-list new-line

These are the allowed syntax variants for`#define` statements.

`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line-continuation in the macro. What they do is put everything on a single line, so the expanded macro will look something like

```
int main() {
    #ifndef DEBUG_MODE ; #else cout ...; #endif
}
```

This will not work very well with the preprocessor or the compiler.

Instead you should switch the nesting, and use `#ifndef` first, and `#define` the macros in the inner level.